# Media query to test for difference between height and width of viewport

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I know that I can use `orientation` to test whether the width of the viewport is greater than it's height and vice versa. However, I need something more flexible. In particular, I have a navbar at the top of the page and all the content is below the navbar. I would like to test in my media query whether the width of the viewport is smaller than the height of the space below the navbar.

So, suppose that the height of the navbar is stored in the SASS variable `$navbar-height`. How do I test `100vw < calc(100vh - #{$navbar-height})`?

Comment: Well the `100vw` would correspond to the max-width, so `@media (max-width: calc(100vh - #{$navbar-height}))` ...?

Comment: I am trying `@media only screen and (max-width: calc(100vh - 5em))` and it's not working... I guess `vh` does not exist at the time of compilation, which is when media queries are processed...

Comment: I asked this in the discussion about the relevant bug in Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=915190